# Lpt printing via php in linux

Tags: php, linux, printing

Now i'm using java script to print lpt port connected printer would any one help me. but it's need to print the content directly from web application with to lpt printer using php code in linux envroinmanent .

Comment: I suspect this question is rather confused. lpt is the parallel port device on a Linux / Unix system - and applications would **NEVER** access this directly. But 'lp' is a program for sending jobs to printers on a POSIX system (which may use lpd or CUPS as a request handling daemon - which then talks to the physical printers or other print servers). i.e. you need to set up cups or lpd on the system first.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `system("lp file");`?

Pay special attention to the warnings in http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php.